# how can handle firebase dynamic link in android webview

Tags: android, typescript, firebase, webview, firebase-dynamic-links

When I using firebase dynamic link, I got error in android browser 'Dynamic Link Not Found'. I have no application in android, so if the link open it should redirect to the android web view. So it redirecting to chrome, but shows the above error. How can solve this error?

```
   this.http.post<any>('https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=*********', 
    {
      "longDynamicLink": "https://example.com/invit?link=https://example.com/invit/"+id+"/&ibi=-App-Run-XYZ&isi=123456&efr=1&afl=https://example.com/friends/"+id+"&ofl=https://example.com/friends/"+id
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worked when I changed the 'your_deep_link' url.

For example, if you want to create a Dynamic Link to the resource https://example.com/my-resource (a web page, Universal Link, or App Link), you can't use https://example.com/ as the Dynamic Links URL prefix, because doing so would cause https://example.com/my-resource to be treated as a Dynamic Link. Instead, you must use a URL prefix with either a different domain or a different path prefix.

Wrong

```
https://example.com/?link=https://example.com/my-resource
https://example.com/?link=https://example.com/resources/my-resource
```

Correct

```
 https://link.example.com/?link=https://example.com/my-resource
 https://example.com/links/?link=https://example.com/my-resource
 https://ex.amp.le/?link=https://example.com/my-resource
```